# Why would the stress-strain diagram differ for tension and compression in inelastic region?

Tags: stress-strain

The question came to me when I read the following statement: **"The stress-strain diagrams
may differ in the inelastic region for tension and compression. But these differences may be reasonably neglected for most real problems."** The reference is from https://www.coursera.org/learn/beam-bending (week 3, module 17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deforming a test sample into the *plastic zone* changes the microstructure of the sample in such a way as to decrease its ductility and increase its yield strength. This is called *strain-hardening* and is common in iron, copper and aluminum alloys. In a stress-strain test, this effect causes the  tension curve to have a different shape than the compression curve.

BTW in most "real problems" (i.e., the engineering design of real-life structures), going past the yield point is deliberately designed *against* because yielding in a structure is considered a *failure condition*.

This means that prudent design dictates that the stresses everywhere in the structure be *below the local yield point* by a *margin of safety* that varies between a factor of 1.5 to 2 depending on the application.

Comment: Thank you. Is the stress-strain diagram of tension different than that of compression?

Comment: will edit! -Niels